# NLog aspnet-request-ip property only logs the load balancer IP address

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I am using NLog for logging. I need to log the IP address of the user who is opening the website.

For that purposes, I am using the `aspnet-request-ip` property of NLog. The documentation is here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-IP-Layout-Renderer

My layout in NLog config looks like the following right now:

```
layout='"${longdate:universalTime=true}","${level}",${aspnet-request-ip},"${message}"'
```

The problem is - that the logged IP address is the IP of the machine which is hosting the website. But I need the IP of the user who is opening/requesting the website. I need to log from which IP the website is requested/opened.

How can I do this? Or why `aspnet-request-ip` is logging the host IP address, instead of the user/client IP address?

Comment: Is there a loadbalancer in between?

Comment: @Julian Yes. But doesn't the load balancer pass the original request information to the server? So you think my problem is due to load balancer?

Comment: I think the `CheckForwardedForHeader` property is for getting the client IP even when there is loadbalancer or gateways? How to use that property? Like this `${aspnet-request-ip:CheckForwardedForHeader=true}` ?

Comment: yes indeed. I've added an answer to explain a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using a load balancer (so in this case), the request IP will be the IP of the load balancer. Essentially you are getting the request of the load balancer, so that's the IP of the sender.

So you need:

```
${aspnet-request-ip:CheckForwardedForHeader=true}
```

This will get the IP of the X-Forwarded-For header, which is the de facto standard for sending client IPs by a load balancer. See [X-Forwarded-For on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)

> The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) header is a de-facto standard header for identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or a load balancer. When traffic is intercepted between clients and servers, server access logs contain the IP address of the proxy or load balancer only. To see the original IP address of the client, the X-Forwarded-For request header is used.

Note: don't enable CheckForwardedForHeader for no-load-balanced cases, as an user could send the the IP by sending that header.

See [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-IP-Layout-Renderer)